# Requests giving errors while using HTTP proxies

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, request, python-3.9

So, I was sending a request using the `requests` library in Python 3.9.1. The problem is, when I tried to use an HTTP proxy it gave me this error:

```
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002B08D6BC9A0>: Failed to establish a new connection: 
[WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond')))
```

This my code, I would appreciate any help.:

```
import requests
for proxy in open('proxies.txt','r').readlines():
    proxies = {
    'http': f'http://{proxy}',
    'https': f'http://{proxy}'
    }
    e = requests.get('https://google.com/robots.txt',proxies=proxies)
    open('uwu.txt','a').write(e.text)
    print(e.text)
```

I am pretty sure it is not  problem with my proxies as they are really good private proxies with 100 gigs of bandwidth. (from zenum.io).

Comment: check line 5, in that line you must make it `'https': f'https://{proxy}'`

Comment: @xcodz-dot ok c:

Comment: @xcodz-dot did not work :c

Comment: The error says, that it's unable to connect to proxy. Some problem with proxy I suppose. I have not worked with proxy before, so I can't help

Comment: What’s the format of each proxy line? Also, did you try using try/except to go past the failure, and did you actually try connecting to the proxy to make sure it’s working?